# How can I check whether is NULL the result of JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, concatenation

Here is my table structure:

```
-- categories
+----+-------------+
| id |     name    |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | political   |
| 2  | cultural    |
| 3  | social      |
| 4  | historical  |
+----+-------------+

-- tags
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| id |     name    | parent_id | category_id |  total_used_num |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1  | president   | NULL      | 1           | 43              |
| 2  | society     | NULL      | 3           | 345             |
| 3  | Trump       | 1         | 1           | 5               |
| 4  | book        | 5         | 2           | 5473            |
| 5  | library     | NULL      | 2           | 433             |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       CONCAT(t2.name, ',', cat.name) t_p 
FROM   tags t1 
       LEFT JOIN tags t2 
              ON t1.parent_id = t2.id 
       INNER JOIN categories cat 
               ON t1.category_id = cat.id 
ORDER  BY total_used_num DESC, 
          t1.id 

/* output
+----+-------------+--------------------------+
| 1  | president   | NULL                     |
| 2  | society     | NULL                     |
| 3  | Trump       | president,political      |
| 4  | book        | library,cultural         |
| 5  | library     | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+
```

See? The result of `CONCAT` with `NULL`, is `NULL`. Anyway, how can I avoid that? Also I want to make that comma `,` conditional. If both field aren't `NULL`, then that comma should be there. This is **expected result**:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+
| 1  | president   | political                |
| 2  | society     | social                   |
| 3  | Trump       | president,political      |
| 4  | book        | library,cultural         |
| 5  | library     | cultural                 |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `concat_ws()`:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       CONCAT_WS(',', t2.name, cat.name) as t_p 
FROM tags t1 LEFT JOIN
     tags t2 
     ON t1.parent_id = t2.id INNER JOIN
     categories cat 
     ON t1.category_id = cat.id 
ORDER BY total_used_num DESC, t1.id ;
```

Comment: Who the hell are you? Did you even read my question in less than 1 min?! Really  great and great you are. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement. Here is the Oracle query, you can modify it for MySQL:

```
SELECT   t1.name, 
            (case when t2.name is not null then ( t2.name || ', ') else '' end)  || cat.name 
FROM   tags t1 
       LEFT JOIN tags t2 
              ON t1.parent_id = t2.id 
       INNER JOIN categories cat 
               ON t1.category_id = cat.id  
ORDER  BY t1.total_used_num DESC, 
          t1.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use CASE WHEN Statement so that you will get the expected output.
Refer the code below.

```
SELECT t1.name,  (CASE 
                WHEN  (t2.name IS NULL) 
                THEN  cat.name
                ELSE (CONCAT(t2.name, ',', cat.name))
                END) AS t_p 
FROM   tags t1 
       LEFT JOIN tags t2 
              ON t1.parent_id = t2.id 
       INNER JOIN categories cat 
               ON t1.category_id = cat.id
```